# fs2-kafka consumer getting type mismatch error found fs2.stream required cats.effect.IO

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, scala-cats, fs2

I've been following the examples for [fs2-kafka](https://index.scala-lang.org/ovotech/fs2-kafka-client/fs2-kafka-client/0.2.2?target=_2.12). However I've qot quite stuck on the example for a consumer. The problem I get is a type mismatch between an fs2.stream and cats.effect.IO (error below)

The code: NB: *Now updated with the recommendation from @AlexeyNovakov to provide a working example*

```
package pb.streams

import cats.effect.{ContextShift, Timer}

import fs2.kafka._
import fs2.kafka.{AutoOffsetReset, ConsumerSettings}
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization._

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, ExecutionContextExecutor}
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import cats.implicits._
import cats.effect.IO

object Consumer {

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutor =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ForkJoinPool(4))

  implicit val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ec)
  implicit val timer: Timer[IO] = IO.timer(ec)


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    consumeFeed()
    ()
  }

  def processRecord(record: ConsumerRecord[String, String]): IO[Unit] = {
    println(s"${record.key()} => ${record.value()}")

    IO.unit
  }

  def consumeFeed()= {


    val consumerSettings = (executionContext: ExecutionContext) ⇒
      ConsumerSettings(
        keyDeserializer   = new StringDeserializer,
        valueDeserializer = new StringDeserializer,
        executionContext  = executionContext
      )
        .withAutoOffsetReset(AutoOffsetReset.Earliest)
        .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
        .withPollTimeout(250.milliseconds)
        .withGroupId("group")

      for {
        executionContext    ← consumerExecutionContextStream[IO]
        consumer            ← consumerStream[IO].using(consumerSettings(executionContext))
        _                   ← fs2.Stream.eval(consumer.subscribeTo("topic-inbox"))
        _                   ← consumer.stream
                              .mapAsync( 4) { message ⇒
                                processRecord(message.record)
                                  .as(message.committableOffset)
                              }
                              .groupWithin(500, 15.seconds)
                              .map(_.foldLeft(CommittableOffsetBatch.empty[IO])(_ updated _))
                              .evalMap(_.commit)
      } yield ()

  }
}
```

The error I seem to get on compiling this is:

```
Error:(55, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : fs2.Stream[[x]cats.effect.IO[x],Unit]
 required: cats.effect.IO[?]
        _                   ← consumer.stream

Error:(54, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : cats.effect.IO[Nothing]
 required: fs2.Stream[?,?]
        _                   ← consumer.subscribeTo("topic-inbox")

Error:(55, 9) parameter value consumer in value $anonfun is never used
        consumer            ← consumerStream[IO].using(consumerSettings(executionContext))
```

Can anyone offer any insight to help me understand and fix this cryptic error? I've tried various attempts to resolve this but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated as I can't seem to google a similar situation.

Comment: it seems there is some issue in documentation. When I align a type in the `for-comprehension`, then it compiles. Can you try to wrap line 54 to f2.Stream type: `fs2.Stream.eval(consumer.subscribe(NonEmptyList.one("my-topic")))`?

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyNovakov that's fixed my issue :-)